# Why does the "else" exist in Python

Tags: python

Why does the "else" statement exist in Python if "elif" can do everything "else" can? Are there optimization benefits to using else, is it an artifact of the history of programming, or is it something else altogether?

Comment: I think it's convenience. You also don't need elif, if is sufficient. Or for could go too in favor of while.

Comment: How does `elif` do everything `else` does, if you need to specify a condition for one, and not for another? `else` catches everything that does not fit in `if`, `elif` catches only what satisfies its condition.

Comment: you could in theory go `if a:  .... elif not a: `   but in my opinion if else is clearer.

Comment: `else` vs `elif True` - clearly `else` is more clear and explicit

Comment: elif is expendable, else is not. The question should instead be "why does elif exist". answer is for convenience.

Comment: @ChristianSloper @buran by that logic you could do away with `elif` too, just chain `if a...if not a` statements

Comment: elif True would not pass code review on my team :-)

Comment: @ChristianSloper, of course it will not pass any code review :-)

Comment: Why don't we make electronic circuit diagrams only with nor gates ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a clear difference in the roles of `else` and `elif`.  The else statement is necessary to handle **any condition** outside of the if statement. However, the elif statement gets called when **another specific condition**  outside of the if statement is met .

Answer (score 1):

The **else** keyword provides an action to take when "if" and "elif" conditions are **not meet**.

if/else logic has been a fundamental concept in modern programming languages. "elif" is an explicit keyword in Python for a conditional else clause (i.e., else if some condition then do something). Else is the last action to take if all the other `if` and `ifel` conitions are false.

```
if condition1:
  action1
elif condition2:
  action2
else:
  action3
```

**Example:**

```python
if x < 0:
  x = 0
  print('Negative changed to zero')
elif x == 0:
  print('Zero')
elif x == 1:
  print('Single')
else:
  print('More')
```

For details see [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically, you could replace all occurrences of else statements by `elif True`. If there was a good reason for doing so, I expect the interpreter to optimize those cases.

Sao, the only reasons are probably readability, familiarity and brevity. Else statements are common in other languages, they are needed frequently and they look more familiar than `elif True`, which looks a bit weird.

Also, why would you use elif in cases where else is a good match?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x + 1 == 3):
    doSomething()
elif (x + 1 == 4):
    doSomethingElse()
else:
    doThisMost()
```

The else statement in this code would catch anything that doesn't equal 3 or 4, which would require infinite elif statements to do otherwise.

Comment: or just elif True instead of else.  You should read the comment section i think.

Comment: Good point. The comments weren't there when I posted this, so not sure how I could of read them.. With that said though, using elif True seems incredibly redundant with the existence of else.

Comment: I totally agree, elif True is an abomination :-)

Comment: It wouldn't require infinite `elif`. Even without `elif True`, you could write `elif x + 1 not in [3, 4]` or something similar.